# How to test this code effectively?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, concurrency

My apologies for throwing this random subject, but I did not come up with a better name,

```
class ReportSenderRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final LPLogCompressor compressor;

    public ReportSenderRunnable(final LPLogCompressor compressor) {
      this.compressor = compressor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      executeTasks();
    }

    private void executeTasks() {
      try {
//        compressor.compress();
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.COMPRESSING;
        System.out.println("compressing for 10 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
        logCompressionError(e.getMessage());
      } /*catch (final IOException e) {
        logCompressionError(e.getMessage());
      }*/ catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logCompressionError(e.getMessage());
      }

      try {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.SENDING;
        System.out.println("sending for 10 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_SENDING;
      }

      try {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.SUBMITTING_REPORT;
        System.out.println("submitting report for 10 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_SUBMITTING_REPORT;
      }
      System.out.println("Report Sender completed");
      reportStatus = ReportStatus.DONE;
    }

    private void logCompressionError(final String cause) {
      logError(ReportStatus.COMPRESSING, cause);
      reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_COMPRESSION;
    }

    private void logError(final ReportStatus status, final String cause) {
      LOGGER.error("{} - {}", status, cause);
    }
  }
```

Ideally, statements like

```
System.out.println("sending for 10 seconds");
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

will be replaced by actual tasks, but for now assuming this is the case, and they way it runs is

```
  private void submitJob() {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
      final LPLogCompressor lpLogCompressor = getLpLogCompressor();
      executorService.execute(getReportSenderRunnable(lpLogCompressor));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_COMPRESSION;
      LOGGER.debug("Error in starting compression: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("started Report Sender Job");
  }
```

My question was how to effectively test this code? The one I wrote is

```
 @Test
  public void testJobAllStages() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    final ReportSender reportSender = spy(new ReportSender());
    doReturn(compressor).when(reportSender).getLpLogCompressor();
    when(compressor.compress()).thenReturn("nothing");
    reportSender.sendAndReturnStatus();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    assertEquals(ReportStatus.COMPRESSING, reportSender.getCurrentStatus());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    assertEquals(ReportStatus.SENDING, reportSender.getCurrentStatus());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    assertEquals(ReportStatus.SUBMITTING_REPORT, reportSender.getCurrentStatus());
  }
```

This runs well for above code.
To me this is crappy for following reasons

1. Not all tasks would take same time in ideal cases
2. Testing with `Thread.sleep` will take too much time and also adds non-determinism.

**Question**

1. How do I test this effectively?

Comment: Presumably your `ReportSender` will invoke methods on some services - compression server, sending service.  Mock those services and test that those methods are invoked and that they are invoked in the right order.

Comment: Thank you @BoristheSpider for your words, I made the changes to the code and added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `@Boris the Spider` comment, I made use of mocks and here is what my tests look like

```
  @Mock
  private ReportSenderRunnable reportSenderRunnable;

  @Mock
  private LPLogCompressor compressor;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test(timeout = 1000)
  public void testJobNoException() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    final ReportSender reportSender = spy(new ReportSender());
    doReturn(compressor).when(reportSender).getLpLogCompressor();
    when(compressor.compress()).thenReturn("nothing");
    reportSender.sendAndReturnStatus();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    assertEquals("Job must be completed successfully", ReportStatus.DONE,
                 reportSender.getCurrentStatus());
  }

  @Test(timeout = 1000)
  public void testJobWithIllegalStateException() throws Exception {
    final ReportSender reportSender = spy(new ReportSender());
    doReturn(compressor).when(reportSender).getLpLogCompressor();
    doThrow(IllegalStateException.class).when(compressor).compress();
    reportSender.sendAndReturnStatus();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    assertEquals("Job must failed during compression", ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_COMPRESSION,
                 reportSender.getCurrentStatus());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class with a method (e.g., TimedAssertion.waitForCallable) that accepts a Callable, which then uses an ExecutorService to execute that Callable every second until it returns true. If it doesn't return true in a specific period of time, it fails.

You would then call that class from your test like this:

```
boolean result;
result = new TimedAssertion().waitForCallable(() -> 
    reportSender.getCurrentStatus() == ReportStatus.COMPRESSING);
assertTrue(result);
result = new TimedAssertion().waitForCallable(() -> 
    reportSender.getCurrentStatus() == ReportStatus.SENDING);
assertTrue(result);
```

...etc. This way, you can easily wait for a particular state in your code to be true, without waiting too long -- and you can reuse this new class anywhere that you need this sort of assertion.